# Set Working Directory in Netbeans in Drools Planner example

Tags: netbeans, drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

when I build the Drools Planner Examples pom project i get these errors on tests:

> Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.624 sec <<< FAILURE!
>   solveModel_a2_1(org.drools.planner.examples.cloudbalancing.CloudBalancingPerformanceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.219 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The directory dataDir (C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Projects\Drools planner\examples\sources\data\cloudbalancing) does not exist. The working directory should be set to the directory that contains the data directory. This is different in a git clone (drools-planner/drools-planner-examples) and the release zip (examples).

I tried to set "Drools Planner Examples" -> properties -> Run -> Working directory -> C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Projects\Drools planner\examples\data\ but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it to

```
C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Projects\Drools planner\examples
```

That the directory containing the data dir: "The working directory should be set to the directory that contains the data directory."